# Javascript loop, sum and output

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple javascript, or so I think, using "while" loops, "prompts", and "alerts".
I want the user to have a prompt to ask how many items he bought
then I want to take the number he entered and return the same number of prompts for the prices, then I want to use a while loop to total those prices up and add 7% sales tax to the whole thing, and then print the total off in an alert window

So here’s what I have so far:

```
<html> <head> <title> Meal Total </title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var result;
        meal=prompt("Number of Items: ");
     </script> <script language = "JavaScript">
var tip = 1.07; </script>
</head> <body bgcolor = "white"> <center> <script language = "JavaScript">
if (meal> 0) {
    var index = 0;
    while (index < meal) {
        prompt("price of the item");
        index = meal;
    }
};
else if (meal == 0) {
    alert("Number is 0");
} else if (meal <0) {
    alert("You entered is negative");
} </script></center> </body></html>
```

As you can see, I have most of the coding done. I have it detecting a negative or 0 for the number inputed. I need the followign things corrected: First, why does it ignore the number of prompts given for the imput value? When I open it and enter two, only 1 prompt window is shown. Second, how do I sum the prompt boxes?

Comment: This sure looks like homework... You should look at how you increment your loop counter.

Comment: Here's another hint, you don't increment your index.  and you don't store the result of the price prompt.

Comment: Another: `prompt` returns a string, so you have to use `parseInt` to avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean up your code a bit:

- Indent everything to make it more readable
- Remove the `<center>` and `bgcolor="white"` parts since they do not add anything - your `<center>` element is empty, and a page is white by default and `bgcolor` is deprecated anyway
- All your JavaScript code should be just in one block, no need for three of them. Also you should put all JavaScript into the head instead of mixing part of it into the body
- Your code should not work because of your `;` after the `}` of `if`, but since you said it worked partially this probably is not the problem. Be sure not to put `;`s after `if` clauses, though.

A working version: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/2dqSr/.

```
var result = 0; // result is 0 at first
var meal   = +prompt("Number of Items: "); // convert into a number with +
var tip    = 1.07;

if (meal > 0) {
    var index = 0;
    while (index < meal) {
        var price = +prompt("price of the item");
        result = result + price; // add price to result
        index++; // increment index, so that while loop will stop after 'meal' times.
                 // If you set it to 'meal' directly, then 'index' will be equal to
                 // 'meal' after the first iteration, and the while loop will only
                 // run once (after the first iteration 'index < meal' is false).
    }
    alert(result * tip); // alert total price * tip

} else if (meal == 0) {
    alert("Number is 0");

} else if (meal < 0) {
    alert("You entered is negative");
}
```

Comment: Just have one question... doesn't there have to be a space between the + and prompt in "+prompt"?

Comment: @Chris: Spaces are almost never required in JavaScript, they just enhance readability. Here, the `+` simply means that it is a number. You could also compare it to positive/negative numbers like `-5` and `+5` which you write without a space.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var items = 0, prices = [], tempPrice = 0;
while (isNaN(items) || items <= 0) {
    items = parseInt(prompt('How many meals?'), 10);
}
for (var i=1; i <= items; i++) {
    tempPrice = 0;
    while (isNaN(tempPrice) || tempPrice <= 0) {
        tempPrice = parseFloat(prompt('Price for meal ' + i + '?'));
    }
    prices.push(tempPrice);
}
alert('You ate ' + items + ' meals, their prices were ' + prices.join(","));
```

Comment: Almost, but how do I sum the second inputs as opposed to outputting as an array?

Comment: Loop through the array and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

```
};
else if (meal == 0) {
```

That's your culprit. Take out the semicolon. You sound like you're new to JavaScript or development in general, so here's a helpful hint that would have saved you on this: keep the Firefox Error Console open in a new window. That would have shown you right off the bat that you had a syntax error there.